# Repository EF DBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, repository-pattern, entity-relationship, ddd-repositories

my question is a two part issue.

I am using the repository and unit of work pattern with entity framework. I have the following `StockTransferRepository` and StockTransfer is my aggregateRoot.

```
Public Class StockTransferRepository
    Inherits WMSBaseRepository(Of StockTransfer, Int64, Dictionary(Of String, String))
    Implements IStockTransferRepository

    Public Sub New(uow As IUnitOfWork)
        MyBase.New(uow)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function GetObjectSet() As IQueryable(Of StockTransfer)
        Return DataContextFactory.GetWMSDBContext().StockTransfer
    End Function

    Public Overloads Sub Add(entity As StockTransfer) Implements IStockTransferRepository.Add
        MyBase.Add(entity)
    End Sub

    ' removes a stock transfer item
    Public Sub RemoveStockTransferItem(stockTransferItem As StockTransferItem) Implements IStockTransferRepository.RemoveStockTransferItem
        GetObjectContext().DeleteObject(stockTransferItem)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Remove(entity As StockTransfer) Implements IStockTransferRepository.Remove
        MyBase.Remove(entity)
    End Sub

    Public Overloads Sub Save(entity As StockTransfer) Implements IStockTransferRepository.Save
        MyBase.Save(entity)
    End Sub


    ' find the stock transfer by ID
    Public Overrides Function FindBy(id As Int64) As IQueryable(Of StockTransfer) Implements IStockTransferRepository.FindBy
        Return GetObjectSet.Where(Function(st) st.Id = id)
    End Function

End Class
```

Below is my code for WMSBaseRepository.

```
Public MustInherit Class WMSBaseRepository(Of T As IAggregateRoot, TEntityKey, dbErr)
    Inherits Repository(Of T, TEntityKey)
    Implements IUnitOfWorkRepository

    Public Sub New(uow As IUnitOfWork)
        MyBase.New(uow)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetObjectContext() As ObjectContext
        Return DirectCast(DataContextFactory.GetWMSDBContext(), IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext
    End Function

    Public Sub PersistCreationOf(entity As IAggregateRoot) Implements IUnitOfWorkRepository.PersistCreationOf
        DataContextFactory.GetWMSDBContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added
    End Sub

    Public Sub PersistDeletionOf(entity As IAggregateRoot) Implements IUnitOfWorkRepository.PersistDeletionOf
        ' BEWARE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Use with caution
        ' this will completely delete the record from the database
        DataContextFactory.GetWMSDBContext().Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted
    End Sub

    Public Sub PersistUpdateOf(entity As IAggregateRoot) Implements IUnitOfWorkRepository.PersistUpdateOf
        DataContextFactory.GetWMSDBContext().Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified
    End Sub

End Class
```

The code below is used within my service layer.

```
Public Function StockTransferItemRemove(removeRequest As StockTransferItemRequest) As StockTransferItemResponse Implements IStockTransferService.StockTransferItemRemove
        ' create your objects
        Dim removeResponse = New StockTransferItemResponse
        Dim stockTransfer As New StockTransfer

        Try

            ' get the aggregate root
            stockTransfer = _stockTransferRepository.FindBy(removeRequest.StockTransferID).FirstOrDefault

            For Each item In stockTransfer.StockTransferItems.ToList
                If (item.Id = removeRequest.StockTransferItemView.Id) Then
                    _stockTransferRepository.RemoveStockTransferItem(item)
                End If
            Next

            ' now save the stock transfer
            _stockTransferRepository.Save(stockTransfer)

            Dim count As Integer = _uow.WMSCommit()

            If (count > 0) Then
                ' the object was saved successfully
                removeResponse.Success = True
            Else
                ' the object was not saved successfully
                removeResponse.BrokenRules.Add(New BusinessRule(String.Empty, String.Empty, Tags.Messages.Commit_Failed))
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' an unexpected error occured
            removeResponse.BrokenRules.Add(New BusinessRule(String.Empty, String.Empty, ex.Message))
        End Try


        Return removeResponse
    End Function
```

This code is working correctly but I am trying to understand if this is the best way forward for deleting child items from a parent object.

My first issue is that inside `WMSBaseRepository` I have a function called `GetObjectContext` which is casting my `DBContext` into an `ObjectContextAdapter`.

Does anyone know if there is an alternative for DBContext otherwise what is the point of DBContext if all the examples I find for deleting a child object all use `ObjectContext`?

My second issue i'm trying to understand with DDD and the repository layer is that this `StockTransferRepository` is solely responsible for the aggregateRoot `StockTransfer` but I need to delete a `StockTransferItem` from within StockTransfer. Am I doing this correctly with deleting the `StockTransferItem` object using `DeleteObject` within the `StockTransferRepository`?

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. The code does work correctly but this post is mainly about understanding if what I am doing is the right approach or not.

I have now added the following into my service layer instead of going to the repository to remove a StockTransferItem.

```
            Dim product As New ProductInfo
            product = _productRepository.FindBy(1).FirstOrDefault
            If (product IsNot Nothing) Then
                stockTransfer.Remove(product.StockKeys.Where(Function(x) x.Id = removeRequest.StockTransferID).FirstOrDefault)
            End If
```

Inside my StockTransfer model I have added the following code.

```
Public Sub Remove(stock As StockKey)
        If (StockTransferContainsAnItemFor(stock)) Then
            StockTransferItems.Remove(GetItemFor(stock))
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function StockTransferContainsAnItemFor(stock As StockKey) As Boolean
        Return StockTransferItems.Any(Function(x) x.Contains(stock))
    End Function

    Public Function GetItemFor(stock As StockKey) As StockTransferItem
        Return StockTransferItems.Where(Function(x) x.Contains(stock)).FirstOrDefault
    End Function
```

But I now receive an error saying the foreign key is null.

Thank you.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove an item you can use [DbSet.Remove(object entity)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.remove%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). The DbSets are properties on your DbContext and you can use them to delete items.

Regarding your second question, if `StockTransfer` is the aggregate root, then the `StockTransfer` should be responsible for handling the items it contains. You should not be allowed to delete an item without the aggregate root knowing about it (how else would the aggregate root keep the items in sync with a property like `TotalStock` or something)

So instead of having a `Delete` method for `StockTransferItem` on your repository, you should have a `DeleteTransferItem` method on your `StockTransfer` and then past the `StockTransfer` to an `Update` function on your repository.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I Originally tried something similiar to that before I got this example working. The problem I had was that it complained about foreign keys being set to null.

Comment: Yeah, that can be a problem. It probably has to do with a dangling StockTransferItem. Your Repository is implementation specific, you could make sure that the EF implementation removes the StockTransferItem but that shouldn't be something which you would expose to the outside world

Comment: I have updated my OP with the new code I am using. Are you able to provide an example to remove StockTransferItem?

Comment: @user1180223 Maybe you can post a new question with some code and the exact exception and where it's thrown?